# Maybe monad bind function precedence

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

In [this](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Haskell-the-Hard-Way/#maybe-monad) tutorial I've found the following snippet:

```
deposit :: (Num a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
deposit value account = Just (account + value)

withdraw :: (Num a,Ord a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
withdraw value account = if (account < value) 
                         then Nothing 
                         else Just (account - value)

eligible :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe Bool
eligible account =
  deposit 100 account >>=
  withdraw 200 >>=
  deposit 100  >>=
  withdraw 300 >>=
  deposit 1000 >>
  return True

main = do
  print $ eligible 300 -- Just True
  print $ eligible 299 -- Nothing
```

I can't figure out how the `>>=` function is supposed to work. At first it takes a `Maybe a` value as its first parameter: `deposit 100 account >>=`

Afterwards, however it seems to take `a -> Maybe a` as its first parameter: `withdraw 200 >>=` How could this be approved by the compiler? Shouldn't `>>=` always take `Maybe a` as its first parameter?

A possible solution would be if the `>>=` function's precedence would work in the following way: `((a >>= b) >>= c) >>= d`

But as far as I know, it is the opposite: `a >>= (b >>= (c >>= d))`

Comment: You might have confused it with `do` notation: `do a <- b; c <- d; e` is `b >>= (\a -> d >>= (\c -> e))`.

Comment: @sdcvvc: Thank you, this was indeed the source of my confusion.

Comment: Note also that it it's not the "Maybe monad bind function precedence"; you can't have different precedences for different typeclass instances, so it would have to be the precedence for *all* monads' binds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> as far as I know, it is the opposite: `a >>= (b >>= (c >>= d))`

nope.

```
GHCi> :i >>=
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  ...
    -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixl 1 >>=
```

`infixl` means that it's left-associative, so `a >>= b >>= c >>= d ≡ ((a >>= b) >>= c) >>= d`.

It wouldn't actually make much sense if it were `infixr`, would it? `>>=` always returns a monad, and its RHS takes a function. So in *any* chain of monadic expressions linked with `>>=` would be in the `(->) r` monad, which is hardly the most useful one.